# Are there any Affiliate add-ons that have 2-tier programs?

Tags: add-on, affiliate

I'm looking for an affiliate add-on that has support for 2 tier payouts.

Whereby affiliates make a percentage of each sale made by the other affiliates that they have referred.

Answer (score 1):

There are just a few [affiliate add-ons](http://devot-ee.com/search/tags/tag/affiliate) for ExpressionEngine. I don't think any of them supports what you're asking, but maybe it's better to talk to respective developers.

You can consider building something on top of existing add-on, or integrate some non-EE solution (both would require custom coding).